# Cubical approximation theorem for cubical complexes

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology, polyhedra

A version of the simplicial approximation theorem states that a continuous map between finite simplicial complexes is homotopic to a simplicial map after subdividing the domain.

I have found a claim in a preprint from 2008 that no such theorem is known for cubical complexes. Can anyone substantiate or disprove this claim?

Comment: In a cubical complex, you can subdivide in splitting $n$-cubes into $2^n$ cubes in the standard way, and so forth. Is this what you call "subdivide" or you allow more flexibility in the definition of "subdividing"? (In both cases, I don't know the answer to your question.)

Comment: If by "cubical complexes' you mean complexes of cubes, where etc. then the situation is simple and not truly interesting. However, sometime during 1960s I developed the theory of cubical complexes meant as subcomplexes of the full cube complex. Later, together with J.Blass, we have published a series of 5 papers in Italian Academy of Science journal around 1972-3. It contained the whole homology theory, including a homotopy property. Important: the cubical maps were induced by the **projections** of the full cube--a very restricted notion but sufficiently flexible for the homotopy & homology.

Comment: Wrt the last comment, are those papers available as pdfs? Secondly, I do not have Massey's  "Singular homology" available, but I recall he uses a cubical approach. Does he have a cubical approximation theorem? Finally, there are comments on related matters at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3656/cubical-vs-simplicial-singular-homology